# Pandas Dataframe, Grouping or Looping?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
          Col_A  | Col_B  
        +--------+--------+
Index   
--------+--------+--------+ 
Index_1 | XXXXX  | 0      |
--------+--------+--------+
Index_2 | XXXXX  | 1      |
--------+--------+--------+
Index_3 | XXXXX  | 2      |
--------+--------+--------+
Index_4 | YYYYY  | 0      |
--------+--------+--------+
Index_5 | YYYYY  | 1      |
--------+--------+--------+
Index_6 | ZZZZZ  | 0      |
--------+--------+--------+
          [....]
```

I want a dataframe, that looks like:

```
          Col_A  | Col_B  
        +--------+------------------------------+
Index   
--------+--------+------------------------------+ 
Index_1 | XXXXX  | [Index_1, Index_2, Index_3]  | 
--------+--------+------------------------------+ 
Index_4 | YYYYY  | [Index_4, Index_5]           |
--------+--------+------------------------------+
Index_6 | ZZZZZ  | [Index_6, ...]               |
--------+--------+------------------------------+
          [....]
```

My approach would be to group by Col_A and iterate through the rows of each group. Or is it better to iterate through the dataframe itself? Performance is important, since the dataframe is quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to iterate, you can apply `list` directly:

```
df.groupby('Col_A')['Col_B'].apply(list)
```

Make sure to select `'Col_B'` to apply `list` on a series, otherwise `list` will return the dataframe's columns.

---

**Edit**

You can store the original (first) index as follows:

```
original_index = df.reset_index(drop=False).groupby('Col_A')['Index'].first()
```

And then merge the original index with the previous result:

```
result = df.groupby('Col_A')['Col_B'].apply(list).join(original_index)
```

Finally, you can swap indices with:

```
result.reset_index(drop=False).set_index('Index')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this way, the index column is lost, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.reset_index().groupby('Col_A') \
  .agg(dict(Index='first', Col_B=lambda x: list(x))) \
  .reset_index().set_index('Index')
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is most likely faster, it makes only one call to `groupby`. If you find otherwise it would be interesting to know. In the meantime you should accept this answer.